# How to use JS to update text based on selected option value

Tags: javascript, html

This is my select:

```
<div class="quantity-select">
            <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
                <option value="2">2 BAGS, $25</option>
                <option value="3">3 BAGS, $35</option>
                <option value="4">4 BAGS, $45</option>
                <option value="5">5 BAGS, $55</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

This my table of information I want to change depending on the option value selected:

```
        <div class="product-info">
            <table>
               <tr>
                 <td><span id="total-meals">10</span> MEALS PER BAG</td>
                 <td><span id="total-nuggs">50</span> TOTAL NUGGS</td> 
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><span id="chickens-saved">1</span> CHICK SAVED</td>
               <td><span id="calories-saved">420</span> CALORIES SAVED</td> 
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><span id="water-saved">4</span> GALLONS OF WATER SAVED</td>
               <td>100% MICROWAVABLE</td> 
             </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript function that I have implemented to make the total-meals change based on the option value selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateNumbers(){
        var select = document.getElementById("quantity");
        var quantity = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if (quantity == 2)
        {
           document.getElementById('total-meals') = 20
        }
        else if (quantity == 3)
        {
           document.getElementById('total-meals') = 30
        }
        else if (quantity == 4)
        {
           document.getElementById('total-meals') = 40
        }

    }

</script>
```

Why is the total meals not updating - what am I doing wrong. By the way, this is my first week learning HTML/CSS/JavaScript so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some **modifications** like below to make it workable.

**First**: Add an change event on your `select` element like this `onchange="updateNumbers()` so when you change your select option it'll call automatically.

**Second**: Use `innerHTML` property to set value of the element that you get using `document.getElementById('total-meals')` because `document.getElementById('total-meals')` only selects your element with id `total-meals`. You've use `innerHTML` property to set the values.

**Third** :  Use `document.getElementById('total-meals')` only once like my example snippet.(optional but you should be more clear coder and less repeater as you're in the first week of learning html, css and javascript :))

**Fourth**: I think you're missing the last `else if` condition for the `quantity == 5`, if you don't add that it will not show the reflection when you choose **5 BAGS, $55**

`innerHTML`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

```js
function updateNumbers() {
  var select = document.getElementById("quantity");
  var quantity = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var total_meals = document.getElementById('total-meals');

  if (quantity == 2) {
    total_meals.innerHTML = 20;
  } else if (quantity == 3) {
    total_meals.innerHTML = 30;
  } else if (quantity == 4) {
    total_meals.innerHTML = 40;
  } else if (quantity == 5) {
    total_meals.innerHTML = 50;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="quantity-select">
    <select name="quantity" id="quantity" onchange="updateNumbers()">
      <option value="2">2 BAGS, $25</option>
      <option value="3">3 BAGS, $35</option>
      <option value="4">4 BAGS, $45</option>
      <option value="5">5 BAGS, $55</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="product-info">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><span id="total-meals">10</span> MEALS PER BAG</td>
        <td><span id="total-nuggs">50</span> TOTAL NUGGS</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span id="chickens-saved">1</span> CHICK SAVED</td>
        <td><span id="calories-saved">420</span> CALORIES SAVED</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span id="water-saved">4</span> GALLONS OF WATER SAVED</td>
        <td>100% MICROWAVABLE</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` only selects the node for you.

You need to set its `html` to change the content like

```
document.getElementById('total-meals').innerHTML = 20 //or whatever.
```

Or you can also use `Node.textContent` like

```
document.getElementById('total-meals').textContent = whatever
```